# APi Gateway: SDK Settings name given to method does not reflect in SDK Generation

Tags: java, android, aws-api-gateway

Highlighted operation name given to request does not reflect in Generated SDK.

I have deployed onto the stage and generated android & Java SDK, But **"myMethodName"**  is not reflected in generated client[Screenshot below].

[image]

Is there anything else needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip next to the input field says: "Specify a name to be used for this operation in the generated SDK. If one is not provided, the name will be assigned based on the method and path. This value will not be used in the JavaScript, Android, or iOS SDKs.". So it's not expected to show up in your Android SDK.

Comment: Awww, don't know why this restriction.